# File reading in Java

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

Hi Could anyone suggest me efficient of way of getting no of records in a .dat file.
Currently for validating  record count  i am iterating through the entire file . And then once again i'm iterating the entire file for processing records one by one. So I have to iterate through the entire file twice( for  validating the record count and for processing).I'm interested to know if there is any better way to avoid iterating twice as number of records is almost 10K.

Comment: Are you creating the file yourself? If yes, then it is a popular(if not standard) mechanism to store meta-data(eg record count) at the top of the file, or in another file.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why can't you just process the records sequentially?  Why do you have to know the number of records in the file first?

Comment: Would depend entirely on what the format of the .dat file is. Maybe the records are fixed length in which case you can divide the length of the file by the lengths of the records. As is suggested elsewhere here, it is common place in file formats to have a header that includes the number of records. Or rewrite your logic not to require the number of records up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that u try to implmnt the record count functionality and the processing functionality in the same loop.. all u have to do is to keep the record count variable outside the loop and increment it using ++ operator within the loop and side-by-side perform the functionality . in the while/for loop check for the end of file and everything will fall in place.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion sharma . In the .dat file the header record contains total record count.So first i need to evaluate whether the file contains as many reocrds as mentioned in the header .Only if the counts are same  i have to process the file else no need.

Comment: As you said if i'm  doing in single loop for example while processing some 10k th record i found that record count is invalid in that case i've to rollback all the processing i've done for 10k records  and also the time taken for processing those records is also wasted .

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the file in some other module (or at least you have access to that code), You can write the **recordCount** at first line, and whenever a write operation occurs you need to update the **recordCount** accordingly.

Now, while reading the file only one read will validate the record count and if successful than you can traverse the file.

Comment: the header of the .dat has the number of records. i need to validate whether the .dat file contains as many records as specified in the header record.After validating i have to process reocrds one by one.